# Check if box in form has information or not

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check if my last name element has information on it with an "If" statement but i dont know where to place it or if im going about this wrong. The purpose is to eventually check if all the boxes are filled before i can hit the submit button. So whats the best way to go about checking this?

```js
function check() {
  let lastName = document.findElementById('last-name').value;
  addressForm = document.shippingAddressForm;


  addressForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

  });
  alert("Please enter all fields ");

}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="shipping-address-form" name="shippingAddressForm" action="#" method="post">
    <h1>Shipping Address</h1>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>
        <label for="first-name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="first-name" name="firstName" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="last-name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="last-name" name="lastName" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <label for="address">Address:</label>
      <input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>
        <label for="city">City:</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="state">State:</label>
        <input type="state" id="state" name="state" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="zip-code">Zip Code:</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip-code" name="zipCode" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>
        <label for="phone-number">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone-number" name="phoneNumber" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This link might help https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: You can also try using `required` attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

You didn't call the function `check()`. You only defined it.

## Suggested solution

Try this I deleted the content of function `check()`. This example only shows calling the function (but better is using `required` attribute in HTML https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input required is on half of the page)

```js
function check() {
  
  alert("Please enter all fields ");

}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="shipping-address-form" name="shippingAddressForm" action="#" method="post" onsubmit='check()'>
    <h1>Shipping Address</h1>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>
        <label for="first-name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="first-name" name="firstName" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="last-name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="last-name" name="lastName" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <label for="address">Address:</label>
      <input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>
        <label for="city">City:</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="state">State:</label>
        <input type="state" id="state" name="state" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="zip-code">Zip Code:</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip-code" name="zipCode" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>
        <label for="phone-number">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone-number" name="phoneNumber" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

and also if you want display error message with FF

> Error messages
>
> If you want Firefox to present a custom error message when a field fails to validate, you can use the x-moz-errormessage attribute to do so:

```
<input type="email"
 x-moz-errormessage="Please specify a valid email address.">
```